# react-i18next: All namespaces in one file + pass namespace in decorator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I was looking through all the [i18next documentation](http://i18next.com/docs/api/), but still pretty confused as to how to do it. So far I replicated their example and I have the following.

Directory structure:

```
locales
->en
  ->ns1.json
  ->ns2.json
->fr
  ->ns1.json
  ->ns2.json
```

i18next configuration:

```
i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  })
```

And I decorate my components like so:

```
@translate(['ns1'], { wait: true })
```

So I have directories for languages, and than one file per namespace. Each namespace is essentially translation of one view. So I have roughly a mapping from namespaces to React components.

What I want to do is put all those namespaces in 3 files, (because all my components are split into 3 sections of the app - admin, user, common). Each of those 3 files will have a bunch of namespaces. I want to still have one namespace per component, so I want to specify not just the file, but the namespace in the `@translate` decorator, so I don't have to specify it each time in my translate function.

Is that at all possible? If not, can I have all namespaces in one file instead of 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can add more namespaces to the hoc - this asserts those get loaded on rendering (or wait for them when setting wait option)

`@translate(['ns1', 'ns2'], { wait: true })`

ns1 will be the default namespace in the t function passed to props:

`t('key')` -> will search key in ns1

access ns2:

`t('ns2:key')` -> will search key in ns2